# How are Swagger XML comment files included in the ASP.NET Core server?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

I am using Swashbuckle for API documentation, which requires projectname.xml document from the output, but when I build my ASP.NET Core project I don't get that file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger

What should I do when publishing on the server?

```
var xmlFile = "${System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
c.IncludeXmlComments(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile));
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#xml-comments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate XML documentation from code comments. You will want to open project properties on all your projects, go to the **Build** tab, and check **XML documentation file**. This will ensure a XML document is generated in the specified location. You will want to use a relative path for the output directory.